# html-список и js

Tags: javascript

Имеется html-документ, содержащий простой список из нескольких элементов. Нужно, чтобы по щелчку мыши на элементе, его содержание выводилось в js-окно alert. Как это реализовать, какими атрибутами дополнить список и т.д.?

Comment: Спасибо большое за советы, но как сделать, чтобы заработало следующее:
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function (){
    var li_elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for(var i=0; i< li_elements.length; i++)
    {
    li_elements[i].onclick = function()
    {
      alert(li_elements[i].innerHTML);
    }
    }
    }();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <ul>
        <li>Первый</li>
        <li>Второй</li>
        <li>Третий</li>
      </ul>
    </form>  
  </body>
</html>

Answer (score 1):

JQuery:

```
$('li').click(function(){
  alert($(this).html());
});
```

pure_js:

```
function(){
var li_elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for(var i=0; i< li_elements.length; i++){//timka_s, +1
    li_elements[i].onclick = function(){
      alert(li_elements[i].innerHTML);
    }
  }
}();
```

Comment: Во-первых, `li_elements[i]`, а во-вторых, нужно через замыкание.

Comment: @knes li_elements надо перебирать так, по-моему:

<pre>for(var i = 0; i < li_elements.length; i++)</pre>

@ling По-моему, можно без замыканий, this в таком контексте будет указывать на элемент li:

<pre>alert(this.innerHTML);</pre>

Comment: За такую обработку массива надо руки отрывать:  for(i in li_elements)

Comment: @ling, Спасибо, поправил.
@barber, можно и через in. Так короче

Comment: Выполните:

    var arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ],
        res = [], key;
    for ( key in arr ) res.push( key + ' : ' + arr[ key ] );
    alert( res.join("\n") );

P.S: Сколько работал - всегда выдавало 4 значения ( `0,1,2,length` ), но видимо в последних версиях Chrome - `length` сделали не перечислимым...<br>
Поэтому более наглядно:

    var arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ],
        res = [], key;
    arr.my_prop = 404;
    for ( key in arr ) res.push( key + ' : ' + arr[ key ] );
    alert( res.join("\n") );

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое:

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="alert(this.innerHTML);">Первый</li>
    <li onclick="alert(this.innerHTML);">Второй</li>
    <li onclick="alert(this.innerHTML);">Третий</li>
</ul>
```